# Testing property used on mvc controller after injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, nunit, moq

```
public class MyUser: IIdentity, IMyUser{
   // ommited for abbrev.       
}

public interface IMyUser
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    int? CompanyId { get; set; }        
}
```

inside MyController I'm using MyUser besides others to populate
comboboxes

```
public ActionResult Details(int? subsidId = null, int? req = null)
 {
    ...
    MyUser user = this.User.GetInfo();
    var obj1 = ... // ommited on purpose for abbrev.    
    populateCombos(subsidId, user.CompanyId, req); 
 }
```

I'm getting exception on this line populateCombos cause user object is always null.
Inside same controller I'm injecting interface which IMyUser implements

```
[Inject]
public IMyUser MyUser { get; set; }
```

this property is correctly binded using `ninject` (like others in my app)

```
kernel.Bind<IMyUser>().To<MyUser>().InRequestScope();
```

now on testing project I'm initializing controller with mocking requested dependencies

```
[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
   _controller = new MyController(){
       ... repositories....
       MyUser = MockMyUser()
   }
}

private IMyUser MockMyUser()
{
    var u = new Mock<IMyUser>();
    u.SetupGet(x => x.Id).Returns(1);      
    u.SetupGet(x => x.CompanyId).Returns(99);    

    return u.Object;
}
```

and inside test method I wrote simple test

```
[Test]
public void CanDoDetails()
{
   ViewResult res = this.controller.Details(1, 2) as ViewResult;  

   var model = result.Model as MyModel;            

   Assert.IsNotNull(model);
}
```

Question is:

> why I'm getting this dependency (`MyUser` inside `MyController` as
>   `null`) cause it's injected properly? What I'm doing wrong?

Update:

```
public static MyUser GetInfo(this IPrincipal principal)
        {
            if (principal != null)
            {
                return principal.Identity as MyUser;    
            }

            return null;
        }
```

**Update 2:**
Based on Nkosi answer bellow I make following changes

```
public interface IMyUser : IIdentity { ... }
```

and inside Details ActionMethod controller

```
IMyUser user = this.User.GetInfo();
```

and in test method under

```
[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    var mockUser = MockMyUser();
     string[] roles = new[] { "Admin", "SuperUser" };
    _controller = new MyController()
    {
       ....
       MyUser = this.MockMyUser(),
       ControllerContext = new ControllerContext() {
          Controller = _controller,
          RequestContext = new RequestContext(new MockHttpContext(mockUser, roles), new RouteData())
       }
    }

}
```

> ```
> but I'm still getting `IMyUser user = this.User.GetInfo();`
>
> `this.User` is still null.
> ```

p.s. I also changed GetInfo to return `IMyUser` instead of `MyUser`.

Comment: `this.User` is the Principal associated with the controller, and the assumption is that `GetInfo()` is an extension method that creates your `MyUser` based on the principal?

Comment: yes Nkosi, exactly.

Comment: The call to `this.User.GetInfo()` is causing the problem by returning a null object. Sounds like `GetInfo` needs to be mocked out as well.

Comment: I udpated the question with GetInfo method. Basically this method returns null only in testing environment, on the application is ok.

Comment: It's returning null, then you are trying to call the `CompanyId` property on the null `MyUser` object. You will have to do something about that null reference being returned. You could create more mock objects, refactor your code, or fake that `CompanyId`. It depends on what you are trying to test.

Comment: @user1765862 you omitted some properties for MyUser for brevity. include the constructor so that I can update the mock httpcontext to populate the correct identity

Answer (score 0):

What about mocking **controller** also?

```
Mock<MyController> mockController = new Mock<MyController>();
mockController.SetupGet(t => t.MyUser).Returns(MockMyUser());
```

then you can access your controller via mockController.Object and try your test.

Comment: nope, it's mocked already, I mentioned already that MyUser property inside controller is available trough debug.

Comment: Well, so is your problem that you cant set it in tests or when you are running the application?

Comment: inside tests, not in the application itself.

Comment: So where exactly is the problem? What do you mean with "...MyUser property inside controller is available trough debug."? I see that you are getting null from something you did not provide (MyUser user = ....;) what code is instead of the ellipsis?

Comment: just updated the question. Yes, exactly, I dont see the problem either but it exist. Trough debug IMyUser is injected correctly inside controller, yet I'm getting MyUser as null on populatingCombos method.

Comment: I thought I got the answer, but I dont. What type and where did User (probably property) come from? Wasnt it supposed to be MyUser?

If so, now it makes sense. So your property called MyUser is injected, but it does not implement (you did not mock it) the GetInfo() method. So just add other setup to tell the mock what does GetInfo do. It probably just returns itself. Otherwise do not mock IMyUser but some implementation (MyUser) and set CallBase property to your mock.

Comment: user variable inside Details ActionMethod.

Comment: I didnt mention user, but **User**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115314/discussion-between-jan-vargovsky-and-user1765862).

Answer (score 0):

My advice would also be to make `IMyUser` inherit from `IIdentity`

```
public class MyUser: IMyUser {
   // ommited for abbrev.       
}

public interface IMyUser: IIdentity {
    int Id { get; set; }
    int? CompanyId { get; set; }        
}
```

For your unit test to work if you are using the `Controller.User { get; }` is to create a mock/Fake user for the controller. How ever in order to get access to the User, which is read-only, you have to create a mock `HttpContext`. yuck. Luckily you only want access to the `User` anyway.

```
private class MockHttpContext : HttpContextBase {
    private readonly IPrincipal user;

    public MockHttpContext(IIdentity identity , string[] roles = null) {
        var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, roles ?? new string[] { });
        user = principal;
    }

    public override IPrincipal User {
        get {
            return user;
        }
        set {
            base.User = value;
        }
    }
}
```

You can setup the principal to suit your authentication setup with what ever claims you apply at runtime. This is just an example.

```
[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
   string[] roles = new[] { "Admin", "SuperUser" };
   var mockUser = MockMyUser();

   _controller = new MyController(){
       ... repositories....
       MyUser = mockUser
   };

   _controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext() {
        Controller = _controller,
        RequestContext = new RequestContext(new MockHttpContext(mockUser, roles), new RouteData())
    };

}

private IMyUser MockMyUser()
{
    var u = new Mock<IMyUser>();
    u.Setup(x => x.Name).Returns("username@test.io");
    u.Setup(x => x.Id).Returns(1);
    u.Setup(x => x.CompanyId).Returns(99);

    return u.Object;
}
```

This should now allow

```
public static IMyUser GetInfo(this IPrincipal principal) {
    if (principal != null) {
        return principal.Identity as IMyUser;    
    }
    return null;
}
```

To return the `principal.Identity as IMyUser` to not be null.

### UPDATE

I recreated a minimal version of your test using what I provided you above and was able to test it and pass.

```
[TestClass]
public class MyUserDependentControllerTest {

    [TestMethod]
    public void CanDoDetails() {
        //Arrange
        string[] roles = new[] { "Admin", "SuperUser" };

        var u = new Mock<IMyUser>();
        u.Setup(x => x.Name).Returns("username@test.io");
        u.Setup(x => x.Id).Returns(1);
        u.Setup(x => x.CompanyId).Returns(99).Verifiable();

        var mockUser = u.Object;

        var controller = new MyController() {
            //... repositories....
            MyUser = mockUser
        };

        controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext() {
            Controller = controller,
            RequestContext = new RequestContext(new MockHttpContext(mockUser, roles), new RouteData())
        };

        //Act
        var result = controller.Details(1, 2);

        //Assert
        var viewResult = result as ViewResult;
        Assert.IsNotNull(viewResult);

        var model = viewResult.Model as MyModel;
        Assert.IsNotNull(model);

        u.Verify();
    }

    public class MyController : Controller {
        public ActionResult Details(int? subsidId = null, int? req = null) {
            //...
            var user = this.User.GetInfo();
            //
            populateCombos(subsidId, user.CompanyId, req);

            //this is just for matching test expectations
            var model = new MyModel();
            return View(model);
        }

        private void populateCombos(int? subsidId, int? nullable, int? req) {
            //Empty as I have no clue what happens in here
        }

        public IMyUser MyUser { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyModel { }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, I used this approach, but I'm still have the same error message. What exactly is controller variable in Controller = controller line? Inside debugging on ActionMethod I'm getting  MyUser user = this.User.GetInfo(); null.

Comment: typo should be `_controller`, will fix. You should show `GetInfo` so I can see what it returns null.

Comment: I udpated the question with GetInfo method. Basically this method returns null only in testing environment, on the application is ok.

Comment: @user1765862 I updated answer based on additional details provided.

Comment: I updated the question. Still struggling with same exception.

Comment: @user1765862 I created a test using your information and it passed (green) as expected. Take a look at my updated example.